# assigning a ref or reactive a typescript object and looping in vue 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am getting an array of typescript objects and trying to do a simple loop. I am familiar with vue 2 but just now getting around to vue 3.

I get an array of TestResponse typescript objects

```
const props = defineProps({
    test: Object as PropType<TestResponse[]>
})

const submit = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await api.getTest()

        if (response != null) {
            props.test = response.data. <---- Attempt to assign to const or readonly variable
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error while getting the response:', error)
    }

}
```

then I simply try to print them out

```
<div class="text-white">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in props.test">
        {{ item.firstName }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

nothing prints except for the console when I loop over `response.data`.

Comment: But what's the question?

Comment: "Attempt to assign to const or readonly variable" that's the problem.  Don't do the thing that the error tells you not to do.  Props, like in Vue 2, are [read only](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using props (readonly) and trying to update its value (this is wrong for Vue 2 and Vue 3), so you got that error, also, you are trying to access the test object using `props.test` in the template (again, this is wrong for both, vue 2 and vue 3), you have access to `test` directly in the template.

```
<template>
  <div class="text-white">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
      <div v-for="(item, index) in test">
        {{ item.firstName }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  const test = ref<TestResponse[]>([])

  const submit = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await api.getTest()

      if (response != null) {
        test.value = response.data // data should be TestResponse[] type
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error while getting the response:', error)
      test.value = []
    }
}
</script>
```

If you want to use props, then the request should be done on the parent component and the test object should be passed to the component that renders the data, also, remember to not use `props.test` on the template, you have access to it directly using `test`